# How to manually cause an interrupt?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm writing a device driver for a virtual device in Linux kernel. Because it is virtual, may I ask is there any command or technique to manually cause an interrupt just to test my interrupt handler?

Currently my interrupt handler is as simple as this:

```
static irqreturn_t interrupt_handler(int irq, void *dev_id){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Interrupt handler executed!\n");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

And it is called by the probe function:

```
static int probe (struct platform_device *pdev) {
    printk("-----------------------------------------PROBE CALLED \n");
    ret = misc_register(&mydevice);
    printk("-----------------------------------------GOT MINOR:%i\n",mydevice.minor);
    struct resource *r = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    if(r == NULL) {
        printk("platform_get_resource failed\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    irq = platform_get_irq(pdev,0);
    if (irq < 0) {
        printk("platform_get_irq failed\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    printk("Got irq =%d\n",irq);
    ret = request_irq(irq, interrupt_handler, IRQF_DISABLED, pdev->name, NULL);
    printk("Got irq, function returns %d\n.", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

The virtual device is defined in the board as:

```
static struct resource mydevice_resources[] ={
    [0]             = {
        .start      =   20,
        .end        =   20,
        .flags      =   IORESOURCE_IRQ
    },
    [2]             = {
        .start      =   0xC0100000,
        .end        =   0xC0200000,
        .flags      =   IORESOURCE_MEM
    }
};

static struct platform_device mydevice = {
    .name           = "mydevice",
    .id             = 0,
    .num_resources          = ARRAY_SIZE(mydevice_resources),
    .resource       = mydevice_resources
};
```

And also, somehow the predefined interrupt for `mydevice` is 20, but the probe function always says it receives the interrupt 17.

I appreciate any hint. Thank you.

Comment: The interrupt number difference is probably due to your device driver receiving a 'translated' IRQ number. Linux provides a way that each interrupt source can be assigned its own virtual IRQ number for systems with more than one interrupt controller (e.g. for GPIO, each individual port can be assigned a virtual IRQ number even though the GPIO hardware may only have one IRQ number).

Comment: If it's virtual, why do you need an interrupt handler? Isn't a timer good enough?

Comment: @tangrs: Thanks, that problem is now fixed. I still don't know how to issue an interrupt.

Comment: @ugoren: I'm practicing writing device drivers so there's no point to ask why I need an interrupt or not. Basically I just don't have a real device to play with so I used a modified version of ARM-emulator that has an extra device. Because it's an emulator so everything is virtual.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to get that 'extra device' to raise an interrupt in the emulator you're using?

Comment: @tangrs That's exactly what I could do, if I had the emulator's source code. The thing is that I don't have it :((
I would like to learn how to cause an interrupt to the IRQ #17, because I know that my device is given the IRQ #17.
And now it seems without the emulator source code this can't be done.

Comment: You should have the device's specifications at the very least. You could just get it to do something that would raise an interrupt. For example, if it's a real time clock, you could set its alarm value to the next second and then wait for the interrupt.

Comment: @tangrs I only have the resource definition, not even the board file. :(

Comment: How are you going to write the driver if you don't have the documentation for it?

Comment: @tangrs I have the offsets that are memory mapped to some registers, one of which is the INT_ENABLE to enable the interrupt, the remaining are values that could be read from and written to the device. Other than that, nothing.

Comment: What kinds of interrupts does your device have?

Comment: @tangrs It has only one interrupt, memory-mapped to offset 0x00. I don't know what type of interrupt it is, I thought all interrupts were the same type (?)

Comment: I meant, what kinds of events trigger your device to generate an interrupt?

Comment: @tangrs the virtual machine is designed so that if I telnet to its port (5554) and issue `sensor accel 1 2 3` it will cause an interrupt and change the value that is mapped to some offset. I tried that but the count of offset #17 in /proc/interrupts did not change (always 0), so I just wonder if there's any technique that issues a definite interrupt to #17, just in case the given virtual machine doesn't work as it's supposed to.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a clean way to do this. The best way to test an interrupt handler is to just test the driver once you're done writing it. Tbh, this is starting to sound like a XY question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to close my question.
There is no way to manually issue an interrupt.
If using android's virtual machine, there're a limited set of interrupts and signals that can be invoked virtually using console command. This console could be open by `telnet localhost 5554` to the virtual machine.